# Can place flower

Tags: c++, function, boolean, new-operator

> You have a long flowerbed in which some of the plots are planted, and some are not. However, flowers cannot be planted in adjacent plots.
>
> Given an integer array flowerbed containing 0's and 1's, where 0 means empty and 1 means not empty, and an integer n, return true if n new flowers can be planted in the flowerbed without violating the no-adjacent-flowers rule and false otherwise.
>
> Example 1:
>
> ```
> Input: flowerbed = [1,0,0,0,1], n = 1
> Output: true
> ```
>
> Example 2:
>
> ```
> Input: flowerbed = [1,0,0,0,1], n = 2
> Output: false
> ```

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool canPlaceFlowers(vector<int>& flowerbed, int n) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < flowerbed.size(); i++) {
            // Check if the current plot is empty.
            if (flowerbed[i] == 0) {
                // Check if the left and right plots are empty.
                bool emptyLeftPlot = (i == 0) || (flowerbed[i - 1] == 0);
                bool emptyRightPlot = (i == flowerbed.size() - 1) || (flowerbed[i + 1] == 0);
                
                // If both plots are empty, we can plant a flower here.
                if (emptyLeftPlot && emptyRightPlot) {
                    flowerbed[i] = 1;
                    count++;
                    if (count >= n) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return count >= n;
    }
};
```

why there is a need to return count even though in output we only need true or false.

Comment: I would suggest trying to use a better title

Comment: If `return count >= n;` returns `count`, then what does `>= n` do?

Answer (score 1):

It's not returning `count`. The statement is

```
return count >= n;
```

This calculates the result of the comparison `count >= n`, which is true or false. Then it returns that result.